# command prompt, opening a csv file?

Tags: unix, command

how do i open a file csv ? with the last command here vi
it open it the command prompt, but how do i open it on csv file normarlly
without open it on the command prompt?

```
[@dc1-ora rci]$ ls
backup                     diamond20130306.csv
diamond2012_04_30_dev.csv  diamond_points_20120820.csv
diamond20120801.csv        diamond_points_20120827.csv
diamond20120802.csv        diamond_points_20120828.csv
diamond20120803.csv        diamond_points_20121217.csv
diamond20120804.csv        diamond_points_20130129.csv
diamond20120806.csv        diamond_points_20130130.csv
diamond20120807.csv        diamond_points_20130205.csv
diamond20120808.csv        diamond_points_20130306.csv
diamond20120828.csv        diamond_points_20130326.csv
diamond20120906.csv        diamond_points_20130410.csv
diamond20121025.csv        diamond_rental_20121219.csv
diamond20121029.csv        diamond_rental_20121220.csv
diamond20121218.csv        diamond_rental_20121221.csv
diamond20130128.csv        ilx_final_lead_merge.csv
diamond20130129.csv        test_diamond20120820.csv
diamond20130130.csv        test_diamond20120827.csv
diamond20130131.csv        test_diamond20120828.csv
diamond20130205.csv        test.txt
diamond20130219.csv        THH_RCT_RCI_EDM_FILE_01_28_13.csv
[@dc1-ora rci]$ vi test_diamond20120820.c
```

sv
( opens file here  on the command prompt)

Comment: What do you mean by 'open it normally'?

Comment: Do you want to view the CSV in some other editor?

Comment: Excel is a Windows program.  I doubt you will get a current version of Excel to run on Linux.

Comment: sorry i had the linux tag on , i took it off, im actually in windows

Answer (score 1):

On windows/cmd you should do:

```
start notepad++ test_diamond20120820.csv
```

in your case:

```
start Excel.exe test_diamond20120820.csv
```

or for the default application associated with it use :

```
start test_diamond20120820.csv
```

(didn't test I am using linux maybe I will test it later if I reboot)

But I suspect you don't mean command prompt but a linux terminal (because of your tags):
you can use any of those:

```
gedit test_diamond20120820.csv &
nedit test_diamond20120820.csv &
```

etc depending on the programs you have installed
or for the default application associated with it use :

```
   xdg-open test_diamond20120820.csv
```

if you are remotely logged in using ssh make sure you have X enabled

Comment: i actually do mean a windows cmd

Comment: Also if you want to edit in vi just press Escpe and the type the letter "i" After that you will be able to modify the file in vi

Comment: the escape/i part work, but is just a huge csv file , which makes it more difficult to edit, the exccel.exe part is not working ,it be easier to edit in excel

Comment: use: start test_diamond20120820.csv

Comment: the above will open the file with the default programme according to the guide [here](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm)
I realised that it can work like xdg-open on linux.

Comment: for big files on linux I use [geany](http://www.geany.org/) by the way Its really fast with big files. A few months ago I used it for files that were about 1GB

Comment: so excel is not your default application for csv files?
excel.exe should work: [have a look here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/command-line-switches-for-excel-HA010158030.aspx)

Comment: im sorry maybe im confusing you, im actually using putty, dont know if that explains more

Comment: is not from my server

Comment: what's the OS of your server?
either-way because your file is big it's better to use SCP to download your file and do whatever you want to it

Comment: I suspect you are using a linux server check if you can use X forwarding but on windows you need [xming installed](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) but if your file is too large I would still prefer scp. Keep in mind that when using X forwarding on a Linux sever you are using the server's programs which means you should have a look on my second section of instructions(that speaks about linux). To ssh with x forwarding enabled use: `ssh -X <unamehere>@<serverhere>`

Comment: so did it work with libreOffice or some other programme on your server using X forwarding? did you SCP?